# In Weaviate hybrid search, is there a way to control the results based on score?

Tags: weaviate

In Weaviate [nearText](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/vector-search-parameters#neartext) search, one will be able to control results either using certainty or distance. For example, one can set `certainty = 0.75` ensuring that not-so relevant results are not included.

Is this possible in Weaviate [Hybrid](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/vector-search-parameters#hybrid) search? I can only see `score` as part of the output additional information but cannot use it for controlling the results (**e.g.,** a score of > X only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that. You will have to implement that as a custom post processing step. Feel free to raise a feature request at the [weaviate repo](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues) to have this be done inside weaviate itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can, regex the 'original score' from _additional in the output:

```
(Result Set 'vector') Document f33748ae-d8c5-417f-acf2-e6c108d6c67c: original score 0.6587977, normalized score: 0.75 - (Result Set 'keyword') Document f33748ae-d8c5-417f-acf2-e6c108d6c67c: original score 3.310954, normalized score: 0.25
```

use:

```
query = (
        client.query.get('your_class',['prop'])
        .with_hybrid(user_query, 
                     fusion_type=HybridFusion.RELATIVE_SCORE,
                     properties=["prop"],
                    )
        .with_additional(['explainScore'])
        .with_limit(n)
    )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).